# Generalization of multivariate normal distribution and classification

Tags: distributions, classification, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

I am interested in a family of multivariate distributions that can be seen as a generalization of the multivariate normal distribution, insofar as they are defined by an expectation value $\vec \mu$ and a covariance matrix $\Sigma$, plus a monotonously decreasing function $g(d)$ such that the density is
$$
p(\vec x) \propto g \left ( \Delta(\vec x, \vec \mu) \right )
$$
where
$$
\Delta(\vec a, \vec b) = \sqrt { (\vec a - \vec b)^T \Sigma^{-1} (\vec a - \vec b) }
$$
is the Mahalanobis distance. The multivariate normal is of course recovered by $g(d) = \exp (- \frac12 d^2 )$.

My **first question** is: What is the name of this family of distributions?

It is simple to show that for classification of a given data point to one of two or more classes, each of which is described by such a density with different $\mu$ but identical $\Sigma$ and $g(d)$, optimal classification boundaries are piecewise linear (hyperplanar).

My **second question** is: Is this a standard result, and if yes, what is the standard literature (textbook) reference for it?

Comment: To my knowledge, there are two families of distributions related to your description: [1. Elliptical distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution) and [2. Spherical distributions](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25049690).

Comment: Hi @Procrastinator, feels weird to have one's post edited by someone else, but I get your point. – As to your comment, I believe *Elliptical distributions* is exactly what I mean, and *Spherical distributions* are a special case. Therefore I think what you wrote is not a comment but an answer. Thanks a lot! – Using the newfound terminology, a search for its use in classification still turned up nothing, so my second question is still open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the **first question** was given by Procrastinator in a comment: The family is called [Elliptical Distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptical_distribution). The standard textbook reference seems to be

> Fang, K., Kotz, S., Ng, K.W., 1990. Symmetric Multivariate and Related
>   Distributions. Chapman and Hall.

Regarding the **second question**, it appears that most literature on classification either considers multivariate normal distributions or completely nonparametric procedures. I did find one publication though that compares classification algorithms based on different estimators of $\vec \mu$ and $\Sigma$, and does so in the context of elliptical distributions:

> Hartikainen, A., Oja, H., 2006. On some parametric, nonparametric
>   and semiparametric discrimination rules, in: Data Depth: Robust
>   Multivariate Analysis, Computational Geometry, and Applications.
>   American Mathematical Society, pp. 61–70.